# How to get Joomla users data into a json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `jos_users` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$response = array();
$posts = array();
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $id=$row['name']; 

    $posts[] = array('id'=> $title, 'name'=> $name);

} 

$response['jos_users'] = $posts;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```

I want to fetch the user id and name to the json file.i thought id did wrong code.can anyone correct it ?

Comment: what's the problem? What errors do you get?

Comment: http://bluewingholidays.com/results.json ..nothing is there when i update the php file

Comment: 1) did you confirm that you've connected to mysql successfully? 2) confirm that the query ran successfully? 3) confirm that `$posts` gets populated? 4) that `results.json` is writeable and the fopen succeeded? You have a lot of assumptions in that code, and have absolutely ZERO in the way of error handling.

Comment: Why do you write the whole response into the file?

Comment: Describe exactly what your goal is, give an example of the target json array!

Comment: sorry guys i didn't connect the db first.i forgotten it now everything is fine

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$id` variable and then you are not using it...

It seems there's a mess in there with the `$title`, `$name` and `$id` variables.

Try this:

```
 <?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `jos_users` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$response = array();
$posts = array();
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$id=$row['id'];  //change here
$name=$row['name']; //change here

//change variables here
$posts[] = array('id'=> $id, 'name'=> $name);

} 

$response['jos_users'] = $posts;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);


?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this?

Comment: Don't just cut&paste a chunk of code and change two letters. POINT OUT where you made the change, but in a written response and via an inline comment in the code. But otherwise, good catch.

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems some variables are not right.